# How can i check if a value is in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am writing a chess program and this function is what moves the pieces. However it is currently not triggering the condition:
`if self.square in player.position.values()==True:` and is just going straight into the else when I am trying to check whether the variable self.square is in the dictionary position. Is there a better way of doing this? My full code for this part of the function is:

```
if self.square==(-10,-10):
    self.square=squareposition
    print("it gets to here")
    if self.square in player.position.values()==True:
        print("it currently doesn't get to here. It goes into the else")
        for key in player.position:
            pieceposition=player.position.get(key)
            if self.square==pieceposition:
                self.piece=key
                break
            else:
                pass
    else:
        self.gamelabel.config(text="Error no " +str(turn)+" piece on this square please try again")
        self.square==(-10,-10)
```

Comment: Can you do us a favor and print out the output to `self.square` and `player.position.items()`?

Comment: dict_items([('ksrook', (8, 1)), ('ksknight', (7, 1)), ('ksbishop', (6, 1)), ('king', (5, 1)), ('queen', (4, 1)), ('qsbishop', (3, 1)), ('qsknight', (2, 1)), ('qsrook', (1, 1)), ('apawn', (1, 2)), ('bpawn', (2, 2)), ('cpawn', (3, 2)), ('dpawn', (4, 2)), ('epawn', (5, 2)), ('fpawn', (6, 2)), ('gpawn', (7, 2)), ('hpawn', (8, 2))])
self.square=(5, 2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `self.square` is the value you're looking for, and `player.position` is the dictionary, then simply:

```
if self.square in player.position.values():
```

Comment: He wants to look in the values, not the keys